# Issue on Report Edit

Tags: custom-reports

I am trying to edit one report. as soon as i click on edit button of report, i was getting this below error.

*This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
[Minified React error #185; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=185 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.]*

I have gone through blogs and did not get any answer to my question. Could someone help me in resolving the above error.

Comment: @Everyone could someone suggest any solution

Comment: You'll have to open a case with Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Priya, I do not know the cause, but I just received a similar error while editing a report, and I found if I switched to Classic and clicked "Customize" to edit, I was able to edit and update filters.  Once I updated, I could re-run the report in Lightning again.

Specifically, this was a report that contained several filters with "CONTAINS" operators, and one of those filters was like this:

Sample Field CONTAINS ""

This seemed to cause in infinite loop that resulted in this error.  Once I updated the filters to CONTAINS followed by a text string, I could run and edit the report in Lightning again.